# Why does DateDiff return a date and not the number of minutes?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find how many minutes exist between two string.

```
h1 = TimeValue("06:00:00")
h2 = TimeValue("22:00:00")
res = DateDiff("n", h1, h2)
```

However, res = 17/08/1902 whereas the expected result is 960.

```
Sub calcul(hours As Variant, Optional n As Integer = 0)
    i = 3
    Do While (Cells(i, 0) <> "")
        Dim res As Date
        Dim h2 As Date
        Dim h1 As Date
        Dim h As Integer

        If (n = 0) Then
           h = 0
        Else
           h = Cells(i, 7).Value - 1
        End If

        h1 = TimeValue(hours(h)("h1"))
        h2 = TimeValue(hours(h)("h2"))
        res = DateDiff("n", h1, h2)

        ...
```

Comment: the result is 960, maybe you try to format with Date so you get 17/08/1902

Comment: I get 960 when I tried it... how are your variables declared?

Comment: @braX like that : `Dim h1 As Date` and `Dim h2 As Date`

Comment: Then it must be getting formatted somehow... how do you know your value is not 960? are you trying the debug window?

Comment: Try defining `res` as `Single`, not as `Date`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is how you you've defined `res`.

Dates and time values are numbers. Even if you see it as `30/09/2019` or `12:00:00`, actually, for Excel, both cases are numbers.

First date Excel can recognize properly is 01/01/1900 which integer numeric value is 1. Number 2 would be 02/01/1900 and so on. Actually, today is 43738.

For times is the same, but the decimal parts are the hours, minutes and second. 0,5 means `12:00:00`. So, actually, 43738,5 means `30/09/2019 12:00:00`.

Anyways, in your case, you are obtaining time difference between 2 times in minutes. The result is 960, **but** you are asigning this value to a `date` type, so 960 is getting converted to 17/08/1902.

```
Dim h1 As Date
Dim h2 As Date
Dim res As Single


h1 = TimeValue("06:00:00")
h2 = TimeValue("22:00:00")
res = DateDiff("n", h1, h2)

Debug.Print res
```

The code above will return `960` properly. Adapt it to your needs.

**UPDATE:** Because DateDiff returns a Long, defining `res` as `Single` **is not worth it at all**. I did it because working with times, in many cases, needs decimals, but if you are using just `DateDiff`, then you can perfectly do `res as Long` or `res as Integer`.

**Note the difference** between DateDiff and a normal substraction with a simple code:

```
Dim time1 As Date
Dim time2 As Date
Dim res1 As Integer
Dim res2 As Single 'or double if you wish

time1 = "06:00:00"
time2 = "06:30:30"

'time difference between these 2 values are 30 minutes and 30 seconds (30,5 minutes in decimal)

res1 = DateDiff("n", time1, time2)
res2 = (time2 - time1) * 1440 '1440 is the number of minutes in a whole day

Debug.Print "With DateDiff:" & res1, "Normal: " & res2
```

The output of this code is:
`With DateDiff:30            Normal: 30,5`

Using `DateDiff` sometimes is not worth it. Depending on how accurate you need the result, `DateDiff` may compensate or not. I would suggest you to avoid it if you can (this is jut my opinion)

Hope this helps

**UPDATE 2:** About the code above, yes, a solution would be using `DateDiff("s", time1, time2) / 60` to get the seconds transformed into minutes, but this value, because of decimals, should be assigned to a data type that allows it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know `Single` :)

Comment: Could you explain what `Single` has to do with this? `Debug.Print DateDiff("n", h1, h2)` works fine for me without the `res` variable.

Comment: As the  `DateDiff` function returns a `Long`, I suggest to define `res` as  `Long` as well.

Comment: Single doesn't really have anything to do with this. You could use any numeric type (although Long would probably best as that is what is returned by DateDiff). The important thing is that it is NOT date. By assigning a number to a Date variable, you were causing Excel to convert that number to a Date.

Comment: @JvdV I've used single just because it admits decimal values. Integer and Long don't. I know the result is, in this case, 960, but I was not sure if maybe OP could obtain sometimes a decimal result, so I used Single.

Comment: @Dschuli I did not know the function DadeDiff returns always a long type, so actually, you are right. Defining `res as Single` is not worth it. Thanks!

Comment: It's was all just because of curiosity. And Datediff returns a variant long. Hence why I was wondering about the single.

Comment: @JvdV It was because I did not know about `DateDiff` returning a Long, but I've updated my answer with all this new info :)