# vba excel datediff calculates different results

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate time difference in hours between two times.

But i am not getting the exspected result, as a matter of fact the same function
throws me two different results.

time between 14:22:00  and 22:57:48  should come as 8 hours 35 minutes and 48 sec.
However i get two different numbers.

If i store the value as a date i get 14:19:12
If i calculate in a msgbox on the go i get 8,5966...

Neither is correct, or maybe it is using some sort of format i am unaware of.
Screenshot shows both the msgbox and the storage test.
Also posted in exspected result.

Any suggestions?

[image: Datediff]

```
Public Sub DDtest()

Dim EDay As Date
Dim ETime As Date
Dim DtgA As Date

EDay = Format(CDate(Replace(Worksheets("Data2020").Range("E2").Value, ".", "/")), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
ETime = Format(Worksheets("Data2020").Range("F2"), "hh:mm:ss")
DtgA = EDay + ETime

Dim EDay2 As Date
Dim ETime2 As Date
Dim DtgB As Date

EDay2 = Format(CDate(Replace(Worksheets("Data2020").Range("E3").Value, ".", "/")), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
ETime2 = Format(Worksheets("Data2020").Range("F3"), "hh:mm:ss")
DtgB = EDay2 + ETime2

Dim result As Date
result = Format(DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60), "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "Date 1:" & DtgA & vbNewLine & "Date 2:" & DtgB & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60) & vbNewLine & result


End Sub
```

Comment: Please, never ever post your code as image. Edit your question and copy/paste your code.

Comment: Adding to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns comments, what are the values in range `E2, F2, E3,F3`?

Comment: Code added..

E column is just date ie,  in this case 12.12.2019, then i replace to -, because it wont work with . as a seperator, convert to date and format.

F colum, is time..

Comment: But the question is why DateDiff gives two different results using the same numbers.

Comment: What if you define `result` as string/numeric instead of date? Datediff is returning a qunatity in seconds, which is being converted into a date, because you are storing it into a Date type variable

Comment: Changed Dim result as Date to   Dim result as string,   the output was identical.  14:19:12.

Comment: 8.5966 hours would seem to be about the answer you are looking for. Since dates are stored as numbers with the whole number representing number of days from 1/1/1900 and the decimal part being part of the day, the 0.5966 part of one day, formatted as a time, gives you just after 2pm.

Comment: Actually, this has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163903/why-does-datediff-return-a-date-and-not-the-number-of-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60)` will return a **decimal** value, in this case is  `8.59666666666667` **hours**

When you apply `Format` to convert it into `hh:mm:ss`, the value `8.59666666666667` **is not** being treated as hours. Excel thinks it's a decimal value that must be converted into date, and it's being treated as **days**.

In Excel, Dates are always numbers. Integer part is the date itself, while decimal part is time, a part of that day but not the day itself.

First day Excel can use is `01/01/1900` and numeric value is 1, 2 is `02/01/1900` and so on.

So Excel thinks `8.59666666666667` is `08/01/1900 14:19:12`

If you divide those hours between 24, you will get the right result:

```
result = Format(DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60) / 24, "hh:mm:ss")
```

You get this:

[image]

Note the first value is decimal value and the second one is formatted as `hh:mm:ss`. But both of them show the same value, with different format.

**UPDATE:** Actually, if you force your dates values to make a difference of 8 and a half hours exactly, you will see perfectly how Excel works. Same value but with different format.

I've forced dates to be `12/12/2019  14:22:00` and `12/12/2019  22:52:00` and I get this:

[image]

Exactly 8 hours and a half, but first in decimal and second is format `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: I take my hat off..  You sir are a champion. 
Thank you for taking time to explain the change and how i can make it work. Really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you formatting before calculation? If cell value is date formatting doesn't meter.

date & time = 441040.598611111111111

```
Sub calcDatediff()
    date1 = Worksheets("masterdata").Range("C11")
    time1 = Worksheets("masterdata").Range("D11")
    date2 = Worksheets("masterdata").Range("C12")
    time2 = Worksheets("masterdata").Range("D12")

    dtime1 = date1 + time1
    dtime2 = date2 + time2
    difftime = Format(dtime2 - dtime1, "HH:mm:ss", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
End Sub
```

Comment: This hits the core issue and is the answer.

Comment: It's not my table, and its a terrible mess, where there is mixed fields, mixed seperators, cleaning up and creating a new table to use.   :(
Thats why the formatting.